# Error in Prolog Code in Asking questions to user [ Edited]

Tags: prolog, logic, artificial-intelligence, expert-system

I'm new to the prolog language and I want to implement a 4 rules which they are

```
Rule 1:
if the environment is papers
or the environment is manuals
or the environment is documents
or the environment is textbooks
then stimulus_situation is verbal
Rule 2:
if the environment is pictures
if the environment is illustrations
if the environment is photographs
if the environment is diagrams
then stimulus_situation is visual
Rule 3:
if the environment is machines
if the environment is buildings
if the environment is tools
then stimulus_situation is 'physical object'
Rule 4:
if the environment is numbers
or the environment is formulas
or the environment is 'computer programs'
then stimulus_situation is symbolic
```

The System That I need to program in Prolog is :
**when typing go. the system asks the user to Enter the Environment, If the entered text is one of the Environments the system should output the stimulus_situation.**

So, I tried to write this code but It doesn't work And I don't know why if you can help me with that.

```
go:- check(Env), write('enviroment is :'),write(Env),nl,undo.

check(verbal):- verbal,!.
check(visual):- visual,!.


verbal :- verify(enviroment).
visual :- verify(pictures).

ask(Question) :-
        write('What is the Env?!'),
        write(Question), write('? '),
         read(Response), nl,
         ( (Response == papers ; Response == manuals ; Response == manuals; Response == textbook)
         -> assert(yes(Question)) ;
         assert(no(Question)), fail).
:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.

verify(S) :- (yes(S) -> true ; (no(S) -> fail ; ask(S))).
```

I wrote it for the 2 rules in order to try but they won't work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem what do you mean "it doesn't works" ?

Comment: @coder it does not work at all

Comment: what is variable Question supposed to do?

Comment: @Eyal Sir, I'm just new to prolog language & I think it is the message that to be shown to user.

Comment: I tried to run it like ask(What_is_the_Environment?). and it returns true when I type textbook. (when it reads) ,note that the question should not have spaces...

Comment: @coder Okay, But the problem is that I cannot determine what the user has typed. i.e. I cannot code it in Prolog. If you can help me with that.

Comment: You mean in the above example to return textbook...

Comment: @coder Yes Sir ^^

Comment: You cannot remove a question like you did by editing out the details. If your instructor has a policy about not using Stackoverflow for homework, it is your responsibility not to ask. What you did by deleting all the details is definitely NOT OK, and keep in mind that people can see the edits, too, so it is COMPLETELY USELESS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from your comments you could write:

```
go:- ask("What is the Environment",Response), check(Response,Result),write('stimulus situation :'),write(Result).

verify(X,Y) :- yes(X,Y) -> true.


check(X,Y):- verify(X,Y),!.


ask(Question,Response) :-
        write(Question), write('? '),
         read(Response), nl,
         ( (Response == papers ; Response == manuals ; Response == manuals; Response == textbook)
         -> assert(yes(Response,verbal)) ;
            (Response==machines)->assert(yes(Response,object))).


:- dynamic yes/2.
```

Example:

```
         ?- go.
What is the Environment? textbook.

stimulus situation :verbal
true.


?- go.
What is the Environment? machines.

stimulus situation :object
true.
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but there is a misunderstand.
the system that I'm trying to implement that :

Comment: 1- Run the Program when I type ?- go.

Comment: 2- The System should Ask me What is the Environment ?!
If the user typed one of the Environments that had been stated in the rules the System should type the  message " stimulus_situation is " and the type of the stimulus_situation.

Comment: What exactly does check/1 do?

Comment: I don't know For being honest.

Comment: Sir, the Answer should be not the Entered environment, the output should be the  stimulus_situation that is related to it.
for example : 
 ?- go.
What is the Env?!What is the Environment? textbook.
the stimulus_situation is Verbal.

Comment: Thank You sir Very much, But if You can tell me one last thing. This code is valid only for the first Rule only. What modification can be made to make it valid for the 4 rules?! 
Example : 
?- go.
What is the Environment? textbook.
the stimulus_situation is Verbal.

?- go.
What is the Environment? machines.
the stimulus_situation is physical object.